# Proof by induction, that $(2a-1)^n-1$ is always an even number with a > 1 and a, n being natural numbers

Tags: induction

When I tried solving it myself I got kind of stuck at $(2a-1)^n * (2a-1) - 1$, as I haven't done any induction proof myself in a quite a while.
Any help is appreciated!

PS: Sorry if my formatting is wrong, this is my first post on math stackexchange.

PPS: If anyone has seen this question before the edit: I have added that the formula has to be equal to an even number, which I forgot to say before, my apologies.

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to prove?  $(2a-1)^n - 1$ is not a complete sentence.  You have a noun (the expression $(2a-1)^n-1$, but no verb or direct object.  I would expect something like "$(2a-1)^n - 1$ **is** greater than $\pi$" or some such.

Comment: You have to say what it is supposed to be equal to (or how it is supposed to be related): if I say `3=2`, I can prove something about it, but if I say `3` there's nothing to prove.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I'm sorry, I just realized this myself! I have edited the question now. I need to prove that this is always an even number (did not manage to put it properly into Wolframalpha, so I just removed that part).
I managed to prove that it is even for n = 0 and n = 1, but when I say n+1 for n, I get stuck :/

Comment: @NickD Sorry, I have edited the post and gave a little more information in my other comment (sadly I was only allowed to add one person, so this is just to notify you), thank you for the info!

Comment: With your edits, this is a duplicate question.  Hopefully, the linked question and answers are helpful.

Comment: @fleablood Thanks a lot! Just one quick question, shouldn't it be ...-[2a-1]^n-1]-2 instead  of +2, since when you do --1 = 1 and then +2 would be 3 instead of -1? Hope this makes sense